# Sound plays in iOS 10 but not in iOS 8.4 (both in Simulator)

Tags: ios, audio, ios8, ios-simulator, ios10

I’m using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()` to play a short notification sound.  The audio plays in Simulator with iOS 10, but not with iOS 8.

Audio format is linearPCM wrapped in an aiff file, as suggested by the documentation. (I also tried other suggested audio formats to no avail.)

Any suggestions?

I use this code to play the sound:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    SystemSoundID winningSound;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction) playAudio
{    
    NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Winning_Sound" ofType:@"aiff"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef _Nonnull)(url), &winningSound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(winningSound);
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self playAudio];
}
```

Return value of `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID()` is 0 (i.e. no error).

Of note: If I remove the audio file from the bundle, the app crashes. Ergo, the app sees the file, no problem there.

Comment: Maybe the simulator for iOS 8 just can't play it.

Comment: I’ve switched to AVAudioPlayer to resolve this. Still scratching my head.